# How to show "favorites" in a list of news posts, in an app?

Tags: usability, android, icons, design, status

I'm creating a new kind of app where one of the layouts shows only some news with the date it was posted:

[image]

I would like to add a **Favorite** option to every post. So, if a user favorites that news, it will show in some color (like an orange favorite icon) and the news which isn't favorited will have a normal Favorite icon (e.g. black).

The question is, where to put the additional favorite icon in the current layout? Where is a good place, from the user's point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to identify items that have been "Favourited" by the user.

There are design patterns for this. Here's one, in TweetDeck. The illustration shows two tweets; the first has not been "Favourited" and the second has:

[image: Icons and status markers in TweetDeck]

Obviously, hover won't work on an Android, so your icon would have to be constantly visible.

#### More ideas

In the comments you asked for more ideas. You could:

- Change the icon in place (below, left). The drawback is that when several are selected and several are not, users might get confused about what means what. Changing the icon shape rather than the colour might help.
- Add a colour cue to toggled items (below, centre). The drawback is that this might suggest selection, rather than a status change.
- Give the icon less real-estate on screen: the first tap slides the icon into full view and the second tap toggles it (below, right). The drawback is that this requires a two steps.

You haven't provided a lot of context for your question, so any of the drawbacks might actually be a desirable strength, depending on what the user will do next.

[image: Three alternatives]

#### Additional reading

Perhaps you might benefit from a review of the alignment and handling of lists on an Android device:

- [Where to position secondary content](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-behavior).
- [How to style icons](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons)

Comment: Oh, great. Can I've some more example layout? and thanks for the edit too.